# Microsoft MPI v6 and HPC Pack 2012 MS-MPI difference

Tags: mpi

I have two VMs, each of them has 4 cores and I would like to use MS-MPI to run a program using the power of those two VMs. I saw there are two different packages I will need to install one of them. They are Microsoft MPI v6 and HPC Pack 2012 MS-MPI. I would like to know whether if it is enough for me only just to install MPI v6? Does MPI v6 provide the ability to scale computation on more than one computers?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer: http://blogs.technet.com/b/windowshpc/archive/2015/02/02/how-to-compile-and-run-a-simple-ms-mpi-program.aspx

"We recommend that our users use HPC Pack to run MPI across machines. However, you can still run jobs across different machines without HPC Pack, wherein you would need to install MS-MPI on all the machines and start SMPD daemon on each machine using the command smpd –d. Make sure you add the necessary firewall rules for your application."